# Sitecore SXA - Exception calling "Import" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null

Tags: sxa

I followed the steps provided to set up the Sitecore 
creative exchange live: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/creative_exchange/modify_site_design_with_creative_exchange_live

However, upon saving the HTML using visual studio code, I have encountered the issue below. 
[image]

Any ideas, where is the bottle neck? I am pretty sure I have:

- Installed the npm
- Enabled the `z.SPE.Sync.Enabler.Gulp.config`
- Updated the `config.js` from the gulp folder to point to my Sitecore local instance.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked Sitecore logs? You will find more details there.